# variable as field in Django admin

Tags: python, django

I need to use the field of an inline class in list_filter and in my actions, my action requires fields to work. Is a query the best way to do it?

admin.py

```
class TelefoneIPInline(admin.StackedInline):
        model = MovimentoTelefoneIP
        extra = 1
        list_filter = ['nome']

class TelefoneIPAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        def cliente():
                movimento = MovimentoTelefoneIP.objects.filter(id = 1)
                for cliente in movimento:
                        cli = cliente.cliente
                return cli

        cliente = cliente()
        file = open('lala', 'w')
        file.write(str(cliente))
        list_display = ('mac', 'modelo', 'fornecedor', )
        search_fields = ['mac']
        inlines = [TelefoneIPInline]
```

models.py

```
class TelefoneIP(models.Model):
        mac = models.CharField(max_length=12, help_text="Este campo deve ter 12 digitos")
        modelo = models.ForeignKey(ModeloTelefoneIP)
        fornecedor = models.ForeignKey(Fornecedor)
        datacompra = models.DateField(verbose_name="Data de compra", null=True, blank=True)
        nfcompra = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Nota fiscal de compra", blank=True, null=True)
        obs = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)

class MovimentoTelefoneIP(models.Model):
        equipamento = models.ForeignKey(TelefoneIP)
        cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente)
        sentido = models.ForeignKey(sentido)
        nfentrada = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Nota fiscal de entrada", null=True, blank=True)
        dataentrada = models.DateField(verbose_name="Data de entrada", null=True, blank=True)
        nfvenda = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Nota fiscal de saída", null=True, blank=True)
        datavenda = models.DateField(verbose_name="Data de saída", null=True, blank=True)
```